# Laravel DB run two queries at once (SELECT/UPDATE)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, select, laravel-query-builder

I have one table which stores some records as JSON. I'm trying to increment the numeric value of a key from JSON column. Below is the query I'm executing in Laravel using `DB` facade.

```
DB::connection()
  ->select("

    SELECT CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(consumed, '$.max_users') AS INT) INTO @tmp
    FROM subscriptions
    WHERE `id` = '2';

    UPDATE subscriptions  
    SET consumed = JSON_SET(consumed, '$.max_users', @tmp+1)
    WHERE `id` = '2'; 

");
```

It works perfectly ok in PhpMyAdmin however when attempting to execute it from Laravel it throws an exception, that SQL syntax is incorrect (where is it incorrect?).

> `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE subscriptions SET consumed = JSON_SET(consumed, '$.max_users', ' at line 5 (SQL: SELECT CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(consumed, '$.max_users') AS INT) INTO @tmp FROM subscriptions WHERE`id`= '2'; UPDATE subscriptions SET consumed = JSON_SET(consumed, '$.max_users', @tmp+1) WHERE`id`= '2'; )`

My suspicion is `select()` does not allow two different queries to be ran at once. However in this particular case I need them so in order to make use of `@tmp` variable. I could retrieve the value of first query and pass it to the second one using PHP, but for the sake of argument, how to run two `DB` selects at once in Laravel?

Comment: You can't run an `UPDATE` query within a `select()` method. Join them together and run it as a single update query instead.

Comment: @Qirel you can actually run any single query you want in `select()` there just isn't a result set to return so it doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single update query to increment this value:

```
UPDATE subscriptions  
    SET consumed = JSON_SET(consumed, '$.max_users', CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(consumed, '$.max_users') AS INT) + 1)
    WHERE `id` = '2';
```